# Sending a SOAP Request with Query String & POST Data in PHP using CURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies, soap

I am trying to obtain a report from a website which actually has a login mechanism in it. So Far I have been able to do it and preserve the cookie in a file.

```
        $url = 'https://<site>/action/method/blah';
        $options = array(

            'textUsername' => 'alpha',
            'textPassword'  => 'beta',
            'appId'  => 'gama',
            'browser' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0'
        );
        $cookie_file = APPPATH.'cookies/cookie.txt';
        $postdata = http_build_query($options);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $options['browser']);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $result = curl_exec ($ch);

        echo $result;
        curl_close($ch);
```

Now I want to extend this to fetch the report, I intercepted the original request in firefox and It looks contains the following.

```
Headers, Cookies, Query String, POST Data
```

In the Headers, It says that the `request-type : SOAP`
Cookie, Query String has key value pairs and POST Data has a XML doc.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>......
```

Can anyone help me to extend my existing code to send the request to fetch the report?

I need answers to the following questions.

Can we use the existing Curl handler `$ch` to send the second `SOAP` Request? 
If Yes, How can we specify it to use the cookie file I created? 
Also, How can I add the Query String and the XML `POST` data in the request?

Any help would be much helpful.

Comment: Hi Fawzan,

Is there a reason you want to use CURL instead of the PHP bult in SoapClient class? (http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) Using the SOAP client allows you to set cookies etc, and handles all your SOAP request building for you.

Comment: Actually I had to use CURL to login to the site. Can I use CURL generated cookie file in SoapClient?

Comment: No, but if you know what cookies need setting, then you could  call SoapClient::__setCookie (http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setcookie.php) to set your cookies

Comment: Actually my project is bit complex. I need a solid solution. I tried to use Guzzle but it doesn't support SOAP. do you know any alternatives?